# Modal p:dialog leaves background greyed out after closing

Tags: primefaces

I have a web project that opens a modal dialog to display some data. When the dialog is closed after the push of a button it leaves the web page useless since everything is still greyed out (just like it was when running the modal dialog) and no user interaction is allowed.

The dialog:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
>
<p:dialog header="#{workOrderAction.confirmation.header}"
    widgetVar="multi_confirmation_#{loop.index}"
    maxHeight="300"
    modal="true"
>
```

The button being pressed:

```
<p:commandButton rendered="#{workOrderAction.class.name == 'ImmediateWorkOrderAction'}" value="#{workOrderAction.label}" action="#{listWorkOrdersBean.doMultiselectAction(listWorkOrdersBean.selectedRows,workOrderAction,tmpSelectedConfirmationChoiceId)}" process="@this select_choice" update="@form"/>
```

**Anyone have any ideas why this happens?**

Comment: check if you are getting any kind of error on browser console. you may get some error. And try appendTo tag.

Comment: appendTo="@(body)" left me with an error in the server logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a problem in Primefaces. If you ajax-update the block which contains the dialog, the dialog will be updated and the status will be closed. But if the dialog was opened, the modal `<div>` stays visible. You have to place the dialog outside any updateable blocks or to close the dialog before update.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can assure that I close the dialog before update, how to do that?

Comment: In `onclick` of the commandButton it would be possible, because it's before update. Better would be, to place the dialog outside the updated block, and close it in `oncomplete`.
Best would be, to do a  `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("ajaxOk", true);` in the bean and `oncomplete="hideOk(args, "widgetname")"` in the commandButton. And add the javascript `hideOk=function(args,w) { var o = PF(w); if(o && args && args.ajaxOk) o.hide(); };`